# Unable to remap_data while using datapump export

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, datapump, expdp

Could anyone help with my datapump export. I've tried many combinations. But, I'm always getting:

```
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 4932
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 5768
ORA-06512: at line 38
```

Any advice on this?

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
  bar VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO FOO VALUES('hello');
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES('world');
COMMIT;


create or replace package pkg
 is
  function tst(p_val varchar2) return varchar2;
end pkg;
/

create or replace package body pkg
 as
function tst(p_val varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
 return p_val;
end;
end pkg;
/



DECLARE 
  h1 NUMBER;
  l_status varchar2(200);
BEGIN

    h1 := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN(
      operation => 'EXPORT', 
      job_mode => 'TABLE', 
      remote_link => NULL,
      job_name => 'exp_1', 
      version => 'LATEST'
    );

    DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(
      handle => h1, 
      filename => 'export.dmp', 
      reusefile => 1,
      directory => 'DBOUT',
      filetype => DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_DUMP_FILE);
      
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(
      handle => h1, 
      filename => 'export.log', 
      reusefile => 1,
      directory => 'DBOUT',
      filetype => DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_LOG_FILE
    );

    DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(
      handle => h1,
      name => 'NAME_EXPR',
      value => 'IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE ''FOO%'')',
      object_type => 'TABLE'
    );

    DBMS_DATAPUMP.DATA_REMAP(
      handle => h1, 
      name => 'COLUMN_FUNCTION', 
      table_name => 'FOO', 
      column => 'BAR', 
      function => 'pkg.tst'
    );

    
   DBMS_DATAPUMP.start_job(h1);
   DBMS_DATAPUMP.wait_for_job(h1, l_status);
   dbms_output.put_line( l_status );

END;
/
```

Regarding the documentation, it should work. No?

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_DATAPUMP.html#GUID-2C61513F-9040-4CE3-8C22-ED1FA5FF81DD

Any suggestion is more than welcome,

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FUNCTION` argument must be the correct case, and the `SCHEMA` argument must be included and must also be the correct case. This procedure call worked for me:

```
DBMS_DATAPUMP.DATA_REMAP(
  handle => h1, 
  name => 'COLUMN_FUNCTION', 
  table_name => 'FOO', 
  column => 'BAR', 
  function => 'PKG.TST',
  schema => user
);
```

None of those limitations are mentioned in the documentation so I would say that your original code is correct and that this behavior is a bug.

Comment: Hello Jon Heller, Surprisingly, it worked when I added the schema and put the package Name and function in UPPERCASE. Thank you very much !

Comment: I'm getting the same issue ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 4929
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 6378

and I've tried every combination I can think of including making sure package name is upper case and trying with and without schema.

this is Oracle 19.  hence the different line numbers in the stack trace.

Comment: @GHZ I just retested the code on 19c on Windows, and it works for me. You may have to create a support request through support.oracle.com - there may be some other bugs in this package that depend on your precise version or platform.

Comment: @JonHeller Thanks.  Yea it seems to be related to the number of data_remap calls I was making.  I had a few hundred and that always seemed to end with missing package function error (for the remap function) in the log file even though the function was there.  When I reduced it say to 10 or 20 then it went through.  I went back to using expdp and parameter files for now which is a shame as I can't autogenerate the list of remaps.   Will create a support request.